# Splitting Aave v3 position

Tags: aave

Assuming we have a leveraged trading position on Aave using aTokens as collateral and vTokens as debt. Are there examples how this position could be easily split into two (or any given ratio 0-100%) with a different account so that

- Both collateral and debt are transferred to a third party in the same ratio (in-kind transfer)
- Debt is repaid, and released collateral is transferred to a thirty party in the same ratio